# Solve 3D least squares in numpy/scipy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, linear-algebra, least-squares

For some integer K around 100, I have 2 * K `(n, n)` arrays: `X_1, ..., X_K` and `Y_1, ..., Y_K`.

I would like to perform K least squares simultaneously, i.e. find the n by n matrix `A` minimizing the sum of squares over k: `\sum_k norm(Y_k - A.dot(X_k), ord='fro') ** 2` (`A` must not depend on `k`).

I am looking for an easy way to do this with numpy or scipy.
I know the function I want to minimize is a quadratic form in A so I could do it by hand, but I'm looking for an off-the-shelf way of doing it. Is there one?

Comment: The same `A` for all 2000 arrays?

Comment: @Joe K is a variable (badly chosen name I agree), not abbreviation for kilo. Yes, the same A for all K arrays. Otherwise I'd perform K least squares independently.

Comment: Hm, that is probably an optimization problem with n^2 variables, right?

Comment: About which size is `n`?

Comment: @Joe yes it is, just like regular matrix least squares (K=1). It even has a closed form solution as the objective function is quadratic in A.

Comment: Sorry, I meant which range is `n` is in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact the answer was simple, I just needed to create bigger matrices Y and X by horizontally stacking the Y_k (to create Y) and the  X_k (to create X). Then I can just solve a regular 2d least squares problem: minimize `norm(Y - A.dot(X))`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this works if `n` is a small number.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize

K = 5
n = 10

X = np.random.random_sample((K, n, n))
Y = np.random.random_sample((K, n, n))

def opt(A):

    A = np.reshape(A, (n, n))

    # maybe need to transpose X.dot(a) ?
    # if axis is a 2-tuple, it specifies the axes that hold 2-D matrices, 
    # and the matrix norms of these matrices are computed.
    return np.sum(np.linalg.norm(Y - X.dot(A), ord='fro', axis=(1, 2)) ** 2.0)

A_init = np.random.random_sample((n, n))
print(minimize(opt, A_init ))
```

Careful: The optimization algorithms used by `minimize` as default are local.

Comment: Thanks, but I was looking for a way to leverage scipy's least squares directly. Turns out it was possible and quite easy, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I can't help with the python, but here is the mathematical solution, in case it helps.
We seek to minimise

```
E = Sum { Tr (Y[j]-A*X[j])*(Y[j]-A*X[j])'}
```

Some algebra yields

```
E = Tr(P-A*Q'-Q*A'+A*R*A')
where
P = Sum{ Y[j]*Y[j]'}
Q = Sum{ Y[j]*X[j]'}
R = Sum{ X[j]*X[j]'}
```

If R is invertible a little more algebra yields

```
E = Tr( (A-Q*S)*R*(A-Q*S)') + Tr( P - Q*S*Q')
where S = inv( R)
```

Since

```
(A-Q*S)*R*(A-Q*S)' is positive definite,
```

we minimise E by taking A = Q*S.

In this case an algorithm would be:

```
compute Q
compute R
solve A*R = Q for A (eg by finding the cholesky factors of R)
```

If R is not invertible, we should use the generalised inverse for S instead of the plain inverse.

Comment: Thanks. It knew that the objective function was a quadratic in A, so it was possible to solve explicitly. I was looking for a one or two liner way to do it. It turns out I just had to stack my obervations and design matrices horizontally, and fall back on a classical 2D least squares problem.